# Pause in "for i in range" with in python

Tags: python, loops, pause

How can I make a pause in a "for i in range" loop, for example after 100 calls?

I have this part of the code:

```
with open(r'url\url.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for i in range(total_urls):
```

Now I want to make a big pause after 100 calls.

All I find is to do `time.sleep()` or set a random pause between calls, but this is not what I need. I already have a 10 second pause between calls, but I need to make a longer pause after 100 calls.

Comment: What do you mean by *'a pause for a long time'* ? You can specify how many seconds you want to pause like this `time.sleep(100)` (pause for 100 seconds).

Comment: why don't you want to use `time.sleep()`? seems fine for me

Comment: Why do you want a pause and what do you mean by pause? Could you  wait for user input instead? If you are writing stuff to the screen and want to read it could you put it in a file instead?

Comment: @Aymen, it's just to understand, what I want, between every call I have a pause in 5-10 seconds, but I need to set a pause, for example, in 10 minutes after every 100 calls also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
with open(r'url\url.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for i in range(total_urls):
        if i > 0 and i % 100 == 0:
            time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem. It was so obvious :D